# Anyone have any good resources on using client validation with MVC2 and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

Does anyone have any good tutorials on using the client-validation with MVC2 and jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025164158/http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2010/02/27/asp.net-mvc-client-side-validation-summary-with-jquery-validation-plugin.aspx) is a good tutorial for MVC / JQuery validation.

Answer (score 3):

Excellent tutorial from Phil Haack on custom client/server side model validation.  The jQuery bit is towards the bottom: [Article is here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

JQuery validator cheat sheet [here](http://elegantcode.com/2010/03/02/jquery-validator-cheat-sheet/)

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery MVC validators, including writing custom client side validators:
http://www.deepcode.co.uk/2010/08/custom-mvc-2-validation-using-jquery.html

Getting jQuery MVC validators working in ajax scenarios:
http://www.deepcode.co.uk/2010/08/mvc-ootb-validation-when-pulling-in.html